# Проблема при скачивании картинки через requests

Tags: python, requests, base64

**Код:**

```
import magic
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

img_base64 =  requests.get("https://www.nastol.com.ua/pic/201507/2560x1600/nastol.com.ua-143932.jpg", headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().random)}).text
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(img_base64, mime=True)
print(mime_type)
```

картинка которую я хочу скачать: https://www.nastol.com.ua/pic/201507/2560x1600/nastol.com.ua-143932.jpg

**Ошибка:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "test.py", line 8, in
>   
>       mime_type = magic.from_buffer(tender_document_base64, mime=True)   File
>   "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py",
>   line 147, in from_buffer
>       return m.from_buffer(buffer)   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py",
>   line 79, in from_buffer
>       return maybe_decode(magic_buffer(self.cookie, buf))   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py",
>   line 263, in magic_buffer
>       return _magic_buffer(cookie, buf, len(buf)) ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: : embedded null character

**Вопрос:**

Как можно исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 4):

Проблема найдена. Нужно заменить `requests.get().text` на `requests.get().content`. `requests.get().text` следует использовать если к примеру  нужно получить `html`, а для загрузки файлов следует использовать `requests.get().content`

```
import magic
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

img_base64 =  requests.get("https://www.nastol.com.ua/pic/201507/2560x1600/nastol.com.ua-143932.jpg", headers={'User-Agent': str(UserAgent().random)}).content
mime_type = magic.from_buffer(img_base64, mime=True)
print(mime_type)
```